# Reverting ubuntu updates

Tags: ubuntu

I recently installed automatic updates on my ubuntu system and now ubuntu won't load into graphical mode. I have a dual screen setup and manually configured my monitors before.

Is there a way to revert to before I installed the updates?

Comment: Revert to your previous backup?

Comment: In this case you might just need to re-run the video driver config to get everything working correctly - I'd suggest asking a separate question about that.

Answer (score 3):

There's no turnkey command, but you can do it manually.

You'll find a log of recent installations in several forms under `/var/log`:

- `/var/log/dpkg.log` shows package status and version changes;
- `/var/log/apt/term.log` shows a full log of console output during installations;
- `/var/log/aptitude` shows installations (including upgrades) in a terse way.

The old packages might still be in `/var/cache/apt/archives`. Otherwise, you might be able to find a mirror that still has them (I don't think Ubuntu has an equivalent to [snapshot.debian.org](http://snapshot.debian.org)). Then install them manually with `dpkg -i /path/to/foo.deb`.

The symptoms you describe point to a problem with the current kernel, video drivers or X server and mostly occur with proprietary drivers. Usually the problem is either that the proprietary video driver was upgraded to a newer version that's buggy with your particular video card model, or that its compilation failed with the newer kernel.

If there was a kernel upgrade, first try reverting that. It could be as simple as rebooting and choosing the old kernel on the Grub prompt. (Press and hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> when your computer boots to see the Grub2 prompt; with Grub1, press <kbd>Esc</kbd> when prompted.)